# Einstein for Heroku

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres, heroku-api, salesforce-einstein

I am wondering if we have Einstein (Salesforce) available for Heroku, I could only see Einstein Vision as an ADD ON available. We will have a great amount of data stored on heroku and would like to utilize Einstein for running various recomendation etc?

Comment: If it's not there, it's not there. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Are you looking for an addon, an API, what exactly? Be aware,
 [Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Yes, probably an ADD ON. Also, there is Einstein platform services, I was wondering if it can be used with Heroku somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question. I'll give you my perspective as a past Salesforce employee that has worked a bunch with Einstein.
Einstein at Salesforce means many things... but not really related to Heroku.

If you're talking Einstein Analytics (BeyondCore acquisition) you would add your Heroku database as a datasource.

If you're talking Sales Cloud Einstein, or Einstein platform in force.com then you would be required to move the data into the force.com platform. Assuming you have a heroku postgres database you *could* use heroku connect to sync your db to objects in Salesforce. Once that data is in force.com you can then use the Einstein platform tools as required.

Answer (score 0):

Currently if you want to use not only Einstein Vision in your Heroku-hosted apps, but also Einstein Language features (Einstein Intent & Sentiment for instance), you need to use Einstein REST API.